# Как создать рубильник для переключения spring-quartz приложения с кластера на standalone?

Tags: java, spring, quartz

Приложение на spring4+spring-quartz

Нужно вынести настройку isClustered как рубильник во внешние настройки(сейчас все настройки указаны в quartz.properties)

Все джобы, триггеры и scheduler'ы созданы с помощью аннотаций, поэтому я решил попробовать подменить бин StdSchedulerFactory на свой при создании планировщика по расписанию

Сам бин-фактори которым пытаюсь подменить стандарнтный

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public StdSchedulerFactory toggleFactory() throws SchedulerException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StdSchedulerFactory.PROP_SCHED_INSTANCE_NAME, "MyProjectClusteredScheduler");
    props.put(StdSchedulerFactory.PROP_SCHED_INSTANCE_ID, "AUTO");

    props.put(StdSchedulerFactory.PROP_THREAD_POOL_CLASS, "org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool");
    props.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "1");
    props.put("org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons", "true");

    props.put("org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold", "60000");

    props.put(StdSchedulerFactory.PROP_JOB_STORE_CLASS, "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX");
    props.put("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate");
    props.put(StdSchedulerFactory.PROP_JOB_STORE_USE_PROP, "false");
    props.put("org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource", "MyProject");
    props.put("org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix", "QRTZ_");
    props.put("org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered", "true");
    props.put("org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval", "20000");
    props.put("org.quartz.dataSource.MyProject.jndiURL", "java:comp/env/jdbc/MyProject");

    StdSchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    schedulerFactory.initialize(props);
    return schedulerFactory;
}
```

И класс, в котором пытаюсь создать планировщик

```
@Bean
@DependsOn(value = {"entityManagerFactory", "dataSource"})
public JobDetail cronJobWorker () {
    JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(QRTZ_JOB, QRTZ_GROUP);
    return JobBuilder
            .newJob(WorkerJob.class)
            .storeDurably(true)
            .requestRecovery(true)
            .withIdentity(jobKey).build();
}

@Bean
@DependsOn(value = {"entityManagerFactory", "dataSource"})
public Trigger cronTriggerWorker () {
    TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey(QRTZ_TRIGGER, QRTZ_GROUP);
    return TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity(triggerKey)
            .withSchedule(createSchedule(TIME)).build();
}

@Bean
@DependsOn(value = {"entityManagerFactory", "dataSource"})
public Scheduler cronSchedulerWorker (JobDetail cronJobWorker, Trigger cronTriggerWorker, StdSchedulerFactory
toggleFactory) throws SchedulerException {
    Scheduler scheduler = toggleFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
    boolean triggerExist = scheduler.checkExists(cronTriggerWorker.getKey());
    boolean jobExist = scheduler.checkExists(cronJobWorker.getKey());

    if (triggerExist || jobExist) {
        scheduler.deleteJob(new JobKey(QRTZ_JOB, QRTZ_GROUP));
    }

    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.getContext().put("SERVICE", service);
    scheduler.scheduleJob(cronJobWorker, cronTriggerWorker);
    return scheduler;
}

private static ScheduleBuilder createSchedule (String cronExpression){
    CronScheduleBuilder builder = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression);
    return builder;
}
```

Здесь, в методе cronSchedulerWorker подсовываю свой фактори и пытаюсь с его помощью создать Scheduler

Все собралось и запустилось. Но, удалил quartz.propepties  и задача запускается на всех нодах одновременно. 
Похоже что мой фактори игнорируется, а в случае если не найден quatz.properties - используется по умолчанию isClustered=false

На правильно ли я пути?
Может быть есть какие-то другие способы, например через jndi ресурс напряму указывать значение в quartz.properies?

Comment: Для начала убери `@Scope("prototype")`, потому что в этом случае где бы не требовалась фабрика, будет создаваться новая копия, а тебе явно нужен синглтон. Потом проверь отладчиком, какая фабрика инжектится в  класс. где находится метод `cronSchedulerWorker`

Comment: И что поточнее тебе надо - переключаться в рантайм между кластер/не кластер, или просто иметь возможность задавать свойство не в `quartz.properties`? Если второе, то там (возможно) можно прямо в quartz.properties сослаться на свойство `org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=${my_cluster_flag_property}`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov нужно именно на момент старта приложения получать эту переменную. А откуда и как прописывать ${my_cluster_flag_property} - его нужно указывать как-то при старте приложения?

Comment: если запускать с `-Dmy_cluster_flag_property=true`, то Ява поместит в System.properties, а Спринг про эти свойста знает. Единственный вопрос - как интеграция Quartz и Spring4 реализована - пропускает Спринг quartz.properties через свой интерполатор или нет.

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov взлетает если понизить версию библиотек до стейбла, но перестает работать распределение задач между нодами на кластере ради чего все делалось.

Comment: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't acquire next trigger: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MYAPP"."QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS"."SCHED_TIME")

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov можете подсказать какой-н другой фреймворк для распределения задач на кластере с нодами по расписанию?

Comment: Мы в схожей ситуации (генерация ночных отчётов и отсылка их по емайл на кластере) делали назначение "лидера" для каждого отчёта через ZooKeeper. Но у нас ZooKeeper уже и так уже использовался, так что дополнительной зависимости и дополнительного сервиса для поддержки мы не получили. Если Quartz умеет на кластере работать, то я бы лучше полагался на него.